# Windows 10 automatically enabling HyperV role

Tags: windows-10, vmware-workstation, hyper-v

The subject says it all. For VMWare workstation to work, HyperV role need to be removed. After I have done that, VMWare works. Then after a restart, Windows would **automatically turn HyperV on**, which causes trouble to VMWare.

Any inputs?

Comment: Sounds like you are connected to a domain is that the case?

Comment: How exactly did you remove the Hyper-V feature? `Turn Windows feature on or off` in `Programs and Features`?

Comment: Yes, Turned it off.

Comment: So it reboot twice too just like when you turn it on again manually?

Comment: No.  First time, it asked (which is normal). Then I restarted manually (restart was required for what I'm doing). After second restart, it re-enabled it.

Comment: `it asked`? you mean like `turn off feature` -> `asked for a reboot` -> `reboot (only once, but NOT reboot -> message about updating system -> reboot again)` -> feature remains on?

Comment: or is it `turn off feature` -> `asked for a reboot` -> `reboot (twice: reboot -> message about updating system -> reboot again)` -> feature is off -> `reboot manually  (only once, but NOT reboot -> message about updating system -> reboot again)` -> feature is on?

Comment: or is it `turn off feature` -> `asked for a reboot` -> `reboot (twice: reboot -> message about updating system -> reboot again)` -> feature is off -> `reboot manually  (twice: reboot -> message about updating system -> reboot again)` -> feature is on?

Comment: @TomYan, Well. Just `turn off` -> `asked, and rebooted`. Then I worked on VMWare-workstatation, and then restarted machine manually (for my work). Woah. I get feature turned back on!

Comment: So in both `rebooted` and the `restarted`, you did not see some message about updating system and the machine reboots by itself once more? That alone sounds a bit strange.

Comment: Actually, it should show `Working on updates` before shutting down, and then it should show `Working on features` after it boots up again, then after the work is done, it will reboot again by itself. This should happen on both turning on and turning off the Hyper-V feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to disable loading of Hyper-V by running the command `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off` and reboot.

When you need Hyper-V again, run `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto` and reboot again.

This is faster compared to going to programs & features and enable it again.

*// Update*

Now in 2020 [VMware used Hyper-V Platform to co-exist with Hyper-V](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Virtualization/VMware-Workstation-and-Hyper-V-Working-Together/ba-p/825831) starting with Version [15.5.5](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/15.5/rn/VMware-Workstation-1555-Pro-Release-Notes.html), so you can have both at the same time and no longer need to run the commands!

> **How does VMware Workstation work before version 15.5.5?**
>
> VMware Workstation traditionally has used a Virtual Machine Monitor
> (VMM) which operates in privileged mode requiring direct access to the
> CPU as well as access to the CPU’s built in virtualization support
> (Intel’s VT-x and AMD’s AMD-V).  When a Windows host enables
> Virtualization Based Security (“VBS“) features, Windows adds a
> hypervisor layer based on Hyper-V between the hardware and Windows.
> Any attempt to run VMware’s traditional VMM fails because being inside
> Hyper-V the VMM no longer has access to the hardware’s virtualization
> support.
>
> **Introducing User Level Monitor**
>
> To fix this Hyper-V/Host VBS compatibility issue, VMware’s platform
> team re-architected VMware’s Hypervisor to use Microsoft’s WHP APIs.
> This means changing our VMM to run at user level instead of in
> privileged mode, as well modifying it to use the WHP APIs to manage
> the execution of a guest instead of using the underlying hardware
> directly.
>
> **What does this mean to you?**
>
> VMware Workstation/Player can now run when Hyper-V is enabled. You no
> longer have to choose between **running VMware Workstation and Windows
> features like WSL, Device Guard and Credential Guard. When Hyper-V is
> enabled, ULM mode will automatically be used so you can run VMware
> Workstation normally.** If you don’t use Hyper-V at all, VMware
> Workstation is smart enough to detect this and the VMM will be used.
>
> **System Requirements**
>
> To run Workstation/Player using the Windows Hypervisor APIs, the
> minimum required Windows 10 version is Windows 10 20H1 build
> 19041.264. VMware Workstation/Player minimum version is 15.5.5.

To avoid the error, update your Windows 10 to Version 2004/Build 19041 (Mai 2020 Update) **and use at least VMware 15.5.5**.

Comment: It doesn't explain the weird issue that the OP was experiencing though.

Comment: @TomYan I have no idea, I always use my trick to get both working (I need Hyper-V for Phone/Mobile Emulator)